# Residuals in Online Gradient Descent

Tags: regression, machine-learning, residuals, gradient-descent, online-algorithms

Does anyone know if online linear learning assumes white noise to the residuals?

My thought process is that serial correlation can arise due to the fact that the fit at time t uses the information from the residual at time t-1?

I have not been able to find any papers regarding this topic, and was hoping anyone in here could provide me with some knowledge regarding this.